# Setting a config value in webpack config and access it from react component

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am working on a project with different brands. I have one generic webpack.config.js and also different config files for each brand. Below is example of one brand.

webpack.config.brand1.js

```
const pageTemplates = require('./page.templates.brand1.js');
let config = require('../../webpack.config.js');

// Set entry point
config.entry.app = './scripts/brands/brand1.js';

// Load in page templates
config.plugins.push(...pageTemplates);

module.exports = config;
```

brand1.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import { LocationChecker } from '../common';

import '../../styles/brand1.scss';

$(() => {
    new LocationChecker();
});
```

What I need to have is a variable (with the value of brand's name. eg. brand1) which can be imported in react component. So that I can check the value and hide/show section depending on the brand name. I would like to set this variable on build-level and access it in my react component. How would you do that? Note: I'm using webpack 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably with [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), which, unlike its name might suggest, doesn't define a plugin but global constants:

```
config.plugins.push(
  ...pageTemplates,
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({BRAND: JSON.stringify('brand1')})
);
```

(or add the plugin to each `pageTemplates`)

Alternatively, if you don't want a global `BRAND` constant, you could create `config/brand1/Config.js`, `config/brand2/Config.js`, etc. outside your source directory and add the appropriate path with

```
config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/brand1'))
```

Then you can just import `Config.js` to access brand-specific definitions.

Comment: Thanks I add it to 'DefinePlugin' and works perfectly. The only issue is getting esLint error for BRAND constant because thinks its not defined! Which I guess I can fix it with changing esLint rules somehow....

Comment: This might help: https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals